# UV-VIS spectra of n-decanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find UV-VIS spectra of the n-decanes.  Specifically tetradecane and dodecane. I can't seem to find such information using my regular search methods, so I was wondering if there was a common database that contains such things that I am simply unaware of (likely).

All I really need to know is if these chemicals will absorb radiation with wavelengths between 355-375 nm. A source to back this up will only help.

Comment: They are colourless liquids ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, ordinary alkanes do not typically absorb anywhere in the UV/Vis region. The organic molecules that do typically contain electrons in $\pi$- or non-bonding orbitals, which have energy level transitions corresponding to UV/Vis wavelengths. That said, I did find one paper<sup>1</sup> describing absorptions around the far UV ambit, where $\lambda < 200\mathrm{nm}$.

1. DOI: [10.1021/jp903435c](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp903435c)

Comment: Thank you for this information.  In addition to the paper you cited there, I found a book - "Spectrometric identification of organic compounds" - that confirms this information.